# After using proc import on an excel file, how am i able to use that data?

Tags: sas

I've imported the excel file and it says the data file work.one has been created, but how am i able to manipulate this file?

What im trying to do is transform PSA to ln(PSA+1) in most analyses using PSA, where PSA is the excel file I imported. I am using base SAS.

This is my code so far

```
data excl; 
    proc import out = psa 
        datafile= "H:\MinitabFiles\Morrell\SAS-Data\psa.xls" 
        dbms = xls replace; 
        sheet = "psa"; 
    getnames = yes; 
run; 

data logs; 
   set excl; 
   sheet = log(sheet+1); 
run;'
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with it?

You'll find it in the work library under the explorer tree assuming you are using Enterprise Guide. To 'manipulate' it, many of your most obvious options will be covered by `proc sql;` or a datastep.

Please elaborate on the question if you want a more useful answer:-
1 which sas product are you using? EG, Base, etc?

2 have you located the file and established it has been imported correctly?

3 `manipulate'? What does this mean? Filter, perform calculations, functions, conversions or one of many other things.

Welcome btw, but please provide plenty more detail.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that it was because i wasn't entirely sure where to start. I added more info to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with your current code. For example the `data excl` doesn't do anything. PROC IMPORT creates the data, the data step around the PROC IMPORT is useless.

```
data excl; *REMOVE THIS, DOES NOT DO ANYTHING;

proc import out = psa  /*PSA is the name of the output data set*/
        datafile= "H:\MinitabFiles\Morrell\SAS-Data\psa.xls" 
        dbms = xls replace; 
        sheet = "psa"; 
    getnames = yes; 
run; *THIS GOES WITH THE PROC IMPORT;

data logs; 
   set excl;  *YOUR DATASET IS CALLED PSA, replace EXCL with PSA;
   sheet = log(sheet+1); *This assumes your PSA data set has a variable with sheet;
run;'
```